# Chapter/Section title in header without numbering

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I want to have chapter and subsection in the headings of my document. but the numbering should not exist.

Comment: "Just to mention"... it would be great if you could provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), since sectional units and headings are very dependent on the document class and packages you are using (or limited to use).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can redefine your chapters and sections?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\mychapter[1]{\chapter*{#1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
\def\rightmark{#1}}
\newcommand\mysection[1]{\section*{#1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
\def\leftmark{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{First chapter}
\mysection{First section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mysection{Second section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mychapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

When you write `\mychapter{Chapter title}`, latex will:

- create an unnumbered chapter with that title: `\chapter*{#1}`
- add it to the table of contents:

  `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#1}`

  (unnumbered things usually don't show up in the toc)
- set the correct title in the page headings: `\def\rightmark{#1}`

Comment: thanks. could you please a little talk about those new commands? I am very new to LaTeX and I am so sorry that my questions seem so simple to the community.

Comment: @Parsa Updated my answer. Is it clear enough?

Comment: does it appear unnumbered in the page headings? + what is the difference between \mychapter and \include{filename} + what is left and right mark?

Comment: Section and chapters will appear unnumbered in the page headings and the table of contents. `\rightmark` controls the right page header, `\leftmark` the left page header. The `fancyhdr` package may help to customize your header and footer. About `\include{filename}` check [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/48097) answer for a good explanation.

Comment: thanks, I do not know how to thank you. Let me check it and I will check mark your answer.